# Unwanted folders created on root directory of published website on easystreet instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, hosting

I have published my website on easystreet cloud instance. It is a Windows Server 2012 R2. But from couple of months I am facing an issue. I found some new folders created at root directory of my website.
The folder contains classic ASP pages with some code and comments which is in Chinese.

Is there any other way to restrict the hacker to upload any folder/files on my website.

EX. Z1.asp file uploaded on root folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was attacked by hacker on server. To prevent this attacks we have blocked the all unwanted ports on server and denied the write permission on folders and files. After that no such infected file/folder generated on server as of now.